# Jest mock looses context, ES Module scope issue?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, unit-testing, jestjs, es6-modules

When mocking a jest module the mock referenced in the definition, implementation and test are different, which means I am unable to assert on the mock.

I'm wanting the same mock to be used in each location

#### Context

I am attempting to spy on a function called from by and action in a React component. I am using react testing library (RTL) and firebase.

#### Setup

setupTests.ts (using CRA and setting up global mocks)

```js
jest.mock("firebase/functions", () => {
    return {
        getFunctions: jest.fn(),
        httpsCallable: (instance: Functions, methodName: string) => {
            return jest.fn().mockName(methodName);
        },
    };
});
```

init.ts (initialised in the RTL render)

```js
import functions from "./functions" 
...
export const cloudFunctions = functions(fb.functions); // Here cloudFunctions.sendEmail mock is correct
...

/** Functions module
    export const functions = (functions: Functions) => ({
        sendEmail: httpsCallable(functions, "emailInvite"),
    });
*/
```

memberFunctions.ts (module with code being executed)

```js
import { cloudFunctions } from "./init"

export const inviteMember = () => {
    ....
    // Here the mock looses its name/context it is still a jest.fn() instances however no 
    // longer has the name set from the mock. Logging here the mock is called and jest.fn 
    // returns the correct information

    cloudFunctions.sendEmail() 
    ....

}
```

ManageMembers.test.tsx (test file)

```js
import {cloudFunctions} from "./init";

beforeEach(() => {
    return jest.clearAllMocks();
});


const mockedSendEmail = jest.mocked(cloudFunctions.sendEmail);

test("should allow administrators to invite members", () => {
    // Test has another jest.fn() reference doesn't include the name 
    // set in the mock also no call information used from the implementation.

    console.log("mockedSendEmail", mockedSendEmail.getMockName()); 
});
```